# How would I install drivers for N900 WNDA4100 wireless adapter?

Tags: drivers, 12.10

I am currently using a N900 WNDA4100 wireless adapter, and I am unable to install the drivers for it. It is using a Ralink chipset http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/Netgear_WNDA4100

I found that Ralink does give support to linux http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501 however, I am still rather new to Ubuntu and I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how I would install the drivers (on the Ralink website for the RT3573 USB).

Comment: Please confirm your device details from the terminal command lsusb.

Answer (score 2):

Props to Chili555 who originally gave these instructions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2089469.html

Except I had to tweak them some, since the website where you get the driver has changed and the name of the folder extracted has since changed as well.

This will let you download the driver and the usb adapter begins to work and networks appear, my problem is that now that I passed that hurdle, I've been presented with another one, mainly that I can't connect to my router even though the network appears and I have the correct WPA password.  If anyone knows what to do from here I'd be stoked.
Running Ubuntu 12.10 by the way.

You will need to download RT3573 USB here: 
http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5034

Drag and drop it to your desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Now we need to modify two files.

Navigate to os -> linux (you can also open home folder and click search and then type in the file names) and open the file config.mk with a text editor such as gedit (right-click -> open with text editor). Be certain these lines are set to =y:

```
# Support Wpa_Supplicant
# i.e. wpa_supplicant -Dralink
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y


# Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Maganger
# i.e. wpa_supplicant -Dwext
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

Proofread, save and close the text editor. Now navigate to common and open rtusb_dev_id.c with a text editor. Make the change I've highlighted here:

```
#endif /* RT35xx */
#ifdef RT3573
{USB_DEVICE(0x148F,0x3573)}, /* Ralink 3573 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x7392,0x7733)}, /* Edimax */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0846,0x9012)}, /* Netgear */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0B05,0x17AD)}, /*ASUS */
#endif /* RT3573 */
{ }/* Terminating entry */
```

All you are doing is adding the highlighted part. All else is unchanged. Punctuation, spacing, brackets, etc. is crucial and must be exact. Proofread, save and close the text editor.

Now we install the necessary build tools:
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic

Now we compile the driver:

```
cd ./Desktop/20120911_RT3573_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0_Rev1_DPO    
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe rt3573sta
exit
```

Your device should now be working.

Comment: The link for driver download is not valid. Use this one instead: http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/rt3573-usb/ Thanks for the great instruction, I have followed it, and now my device is working.